# How to create a new column that contains the sum of all the revenues for a particular Account ID

Tags: pandas, dataframe

df has the following cols, df['Account ID'] and df['Revenue']. df['Account ID'] has duplicate values. Tried the following but it generates empty col:

df['Total_Revenue'] = df.groupby('Account ID')['Revenue'].sum()[image: col views in excel]

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *assign* method to create new column then *groupby* + *transform* to not collapse the aggregation.

**Code:**

```
df.assign(total_revenue=lambda df_: df_.groupby("Account ID").Revenue.transform("sum"))
```

**Documentation:**

- [Pandas - assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
- [Pandas - transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)